# Can I data-bind an element's width only if the element has a specific css class?

Tags: knockout.js

I want to data-bind the width of a Div element to a property of the viewModel, but only if the  Div has a specific css class.

So something like this:

`<div data-bind="style: {width : $element.hasClass('dynamicWidth') ? getWidth : ''}">`

Anyone know if there is a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom bindings for this. Here is simple example:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.widthEx = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var options = valueAccessor();
        var property = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(options.property);
        var className = options.class;

        if( $(element).hasClass(className)){
            $(element).width(property);
        }
    }
};

var vm = { width: ko.observable(100)};
ko.applyBindings(vm);

<div data-bind="widthEx: {property: width, class: 'Test'}">
```

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wRyAg/2/